# overlay showing in background instead of on top

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using Foundation 4 and am trying to have an overlay with spinner while the element is being loaded with ajax. The overlay and spinner are showing, just under the select, so obviously it looks goofy.  In the fiddle, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/jenborn/95pUd/2/

Here's an image of how it really looks:
[image]

i have a div with a select inside:

```
<div class="small-3 columns"  id="DIV_select2"  >
   <div>
   <select id="select2" name="select2" class="medium">
   <option value='0'>None selected</option>
   </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried reducing the select's z-index and opacity, which is happening, but it's not pushing the overlay to the top

jQuery

```
$("#select2").addClass('fadedCtrl');
$("#DIV_select2").fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).addClass('ctrl_overlay');});
```

Here's the css classes I'm trying to work with.

```
.ctrl_overlay {position:relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 60%; z-index: 5000;background-color:#666666;opacity:.8;background: url("/images/big-grey-spinner.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #666666; }

.fadedCtrl {z-index: 10;opacity:.1;}
```

OK, I just tried adding position:relative to .fadedCtrl and !important to position: relative and z-index:10  so that line is now:

```
.fadedCtrl {z-index: 10 !important;opacity:.1;position: relative !important;}
```

It's still not working but it did push the select down a bit:[image]

SOLUTION thanks to Sheng:

```
    .ctrl_overlay {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%; width: 100%; height: 48px; margin-top: -24px;background-color:#666666;opacity:.8;background: url("/images/big-grey-spinner.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #666666;}
form.custom .custom.dropdown {margin-bottom: 0;}
     $("#DIVselect2").append("<div id='DIVXselect2'></div>");
     $("#DIVXselect2").fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).addClass('ctrl_overlay');});
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example in [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com)?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva I added a jsfiddle link and an image.  Can you access that?

Comment: Try adding ``position: relative`` to ``.fadedCtrl`` to allow z-index to work. If this dosen't work, try adding ``!important`` after the positions and z-indices just in case some JavaScript is overriding it.

Comment: Could you try adding this to your stylesheet ? .ctrl_overlay .fadedCtrl { opacity: 0} that would make select hidden while overlay is there.  http://jsfiddle.net/95pUd/1/ Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @ShengSlogar I tried what you recommended, please see my updated post above.

Comment: @scx Thanks for the update to the fiddle.  Unfortunately, on my page it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hold on a minute. I never looked at your JSFiddle because I was on mobile. Now that I'm on a laptop, I click "add overlay" and the overlay appears on top of the select box. Is this not working in your browser? :P

Comment: @ShengSlogar It works in the fiddle, but not on my actual webpage at my site.

Comment: Is there any way I could see the page where it doesn't work?

Comment: @ShengSlogar yes, go to dev.homebrewninja.com/shopping_list, and in the Fermentables section, 1st select, choose Grain and you'll see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is this: setting a z-index won't matter because the select input is a *child* of the div which has the spinner.

This won't work because the div, when the ctrl_overlay class is added, has a background image. This image will appear *behind* all contents in the div.

The solution? Have another div. Use the exact same class, but append a *child* div. This div can now have a z-index higher than the select input. Two children can have different z-indices, but a parent and child cannot.

Comment: I think I made the updates you were recommending, but the overlay and spinner is no longer working.  Did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: Here's your problem: you are using 100% and 60% for your width and height. This won't work (it wasn't working before) unless the parent has a hard-coded width and height. You can, however, use ``position: absolute`` and then you can use a percent. Just not with a static or relative position. Here are your styles: ``.ctrl_overlay {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%; width: 100%; height: 48px; margin-top: -24px;} form.custom .custom.dropdown {margin-bottom: 0;}`` The ``top: 50%`` and negative margin make the spinner centered in the box. I can explain more if you have any questions.

Comment: The reason your spinner was working before, even though the percents were ignored is this: it had contents, which made it have a width and height anyway. So when a background image was applied, you saw it with the width and height set by the *contents*, and *not* the percents.

Comment: Another option for ``.ctrl_overlay`` is if you put an equal top and bottom margin on ``form.custom .custom.dropdown``, you can just say ``top: 0; height: 100%;`` or ``top: 0; bottom: 0;`` so it will always cover the whole thing. I didn't originally do that because your selector height was less than the spinner height, so it would've gotten cut off.

Comment: Note that ``.columns`` cannot have ``position: static`` if you want ``.ctrl_overlay`` to be contained because ``.ctr_overlay`` has an absolute position. Normally, an absolutely positioned element position would be based of the top left of the browser. For example, a normal element with ``position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`` would appear at the top left corner of the browser. When you set the parent element to a position like relative, absolute, or fixed, it is contained, and now the position is based off of the closest parent that has that position.

Comment: The 60% was my feeble attempt to have the spinner only be as tall as the select tag.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Nevermind, I just changed .ctrl_overlay's height to 32px; and it fixed it.  Thanks so much for all your time and help!